# Creating an ArrayList inside a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm attempting to solve a problem that finds the amount of valid solutions to a chess problem and when the code is printed, it prints 92 arrays of an object PartialSolution I made that are the correct solutions. This is done recursively and I need to add these arrays to an array list but I can't figure out how.
Here's my code:

```
public ArrayList<PartialSolution> solve(PartialSolution sol ){
    ArrayList<PartialSolution> solutions = new ArrayList<PartialSolution>();
    int exam = sol.examine();
    if(exam == PartialSolution.accept){
        solutions.add(sol);
    }
    else if(exam != PartialSolution.abandon){
        for(PartialSolution p : sol.extend()){
            solve(p);
        }
    }
    return solutions;
}
```

Comment: do you use `x`?

Comment: do you want to use an arraylist to store the solutions so you don't have to repeat unnecessary calculations? or you just want an arraylist to store the solutions for later use?

Comment: I need the array list to store the solutions for later use @MoeA

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in class and add your lists to that list instead of print. 
 Or make your solve method take a second argument as list and change return type from void to list. For the the first call give it an empty list and pass that list in every recursive call. At the end return that list

Answer (score 0):

If you need the ArrayList just to store the solutions for later use then you should create the list out of the method like:

```
static ArrayList<PartialSolution> x = new ArrayList<PartialSolution>();
```

then just add the solution to the list when you print sol.